# PHP/MySql to javascript not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

There is something wrong with the way I am printing MySQL and the javascript is not executing it. Here is an example.

```
square[1] = "asdfasdfadsf";
```

When I print "`asdfasdfadsf`" from my MySQL database, the javascript does not work. However, if I simply type "asdfasdfadsf" in the static HTML it executes fine. I have tried as many PHP functions and charset conversions as I can. Please Help!

Comment: Is that the actual output you're getting? Are you sure you're not forgetting to quote the value on the output?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function. Apart from properly printing the string, it also escapes all dangerous characters.

```
square[1] = <?php echo json_encode($my_string); ?>;
```

Comment: json_encode() worked! It was because I was breaking the line in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add quotes around the string from the database.

```
// Add quotes around the call which prints the vale from PHP.
// this turns it into a JavaScript string.
square[1] = '<?php echo "asdfasdfadsf"; ?>';
//----------^^----------------------------^^

// Or...
square[1] = '<?php echo $row["value_from_your_db"]; ?>';
```

Note: `json_encode()` is recommended if this is anything more than a simple string that may have internal quotes of its own requiring additional escaping.

Comment: The quotes are correct. The strings will look alike when viewing the source.